# Can't link DB user with social networks with Oauth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I use SpringBoot Security and Spring Security Oauth2.
And i use `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` for login with social networks.
In this filter i use custom `UserInfoTokenServices`, with overrirded `loadAuthentication(String accessToken)`
In this method before return `OAuth2Authentication` i write social user id to DB user or create it, if does not exist (with extra logic i give him some password).

It works fine and later user can login with his email and password, as DB user or with his social network profile and it will be the same profile.

But now i need to link new social, when user already logged.
I tried to use same endpoint /socialName/login, but now `super.loadAuthentication(accessToken)` of `UserInfoTokenServices` throw:

```
Getting user info from: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException, 401 Unauthorized
```

How to fix it? Or what should i do in this case?